# Найти и заменить с условием

Tags: php

WP
Данные из текстового поля попадают в переменную the_content. Нужна функция, которая будет пробегаться по тексту, выискивать таблицы, не заключенные в `div`, и помещать их в него. Каждая таблица в свой `div`.

```
function replace_text($text) {
    $text = str_replace('<table', '<div><table', $text);
    $text = str_replace('</table>', '</table></div>', $text);
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');
```

именно `<table` потому как дальше могут быть разные классы...
Так вот, если выполнить такую функцию по документу с данными, то сработает всё ок. Но если пустить её по тому же документу по второму разу и т.д., то будет получаться `<div><div><table` и т.д. по нарастающей с каждым прогоном функции. Как этого избежать?

Comment: приведите пример того что вы имеете ввиду. сейчас непонятно что за таблицы в тестовом поле и как вы их заменять собрались

Comment: Прочитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve о том как показать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask о том как задавать здесь вопросы, чтобы получить на них ответы.

Comment: поправил, писал с телефона, поэтому было без форматирования.

Comment: @VladimirNovopashin дополнил вопрос, надеюсь теперь понятнее задача